# Is there any way I can find the common addition_cust_base_id from my table with multiple AND operators

Tags: mysql

I want the common addition_cust_base_id  from the table where  addition_id=1 and addition_value='test_data'  and   addition_id=16 and addition_value='test0412'

I want my query to return 65
This is how the table looks like :

```
addition_id   addition_value  addition_cust_base_id 

      1    test_data                   65 
      1    test_1                      151 
      1    test_2                      152 
      1    test_3                      153 
     16    test0412                    65 
     16    test0412                    151 
     16    test0412                    152 
     16    test0412                    153
```

Any idea on how the query should look like ?

Comment: Join 2 table copies, each with its filtering variant.

Comment: and why not 151?

Comment: @nbk . I have changed my table data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join 2 subselects, where you specify the wanted criteria
This will be fastm, when you add a cobined INDEX on (addition_id,addition_value)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE addition (
>   `addition_id` INTEGER,
>   `addition_value` VARCHAR(9),
>   `addition_cust_base_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO addition
>   (`addition_id`, `addition_value`, `addition_cust_base_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'test_data', '65'),
>   ('1', 'test_1', '151'),
>   ('1', 'test_2', '152'),
>   ('1', 'test_3', '153'),
>   ('16', 'test0412', '65'),
>   ('16', 'test0412', '151'),
>   ('16', 'test0412', '152'),
>   ('16', 'test0412', '153');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.`addition_cust_base_id`
> FROM ( SELECT  addition_cust_base_id FROM  addition WHERE `addition_id` = 1 AND `addition_value` = 'test_data') a
> INNER JOIN ( SELECT addition_cust_base_id FROM  addition WHERE `addition_id` = 16 AND `addition_value` = 'test0412') b
> ON a.addition_cust_base_id = b.addition_cust_base_id
> ```
>
> ```
> | addition_cust_base_id |
> | --------------------: |
> |                    65 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a3865556bbfe21f45a8158c1b3b100bc)*

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select addition_cust_base_id 
from the table 
where 
   (addition_id= 1 and addition_value='test_data')
or (addition_id= 16 and addition_value='test0412')
group by addition_cust_base_id 
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=002c9e055214fb9a4e36a648d77ceaaa)*

Comment: @SuryaSingh it works fro me : see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=002c9e055214fb9a4e36a648d77ceaaa)*